# ng-include works for script in index page but not in separate page

Tags: angularjs

I have a folder structure like:

```
www
  partials
    admin
      admin_menu.html
    home.html
  index.html
```

I have defined a script on `admin_menu.html` like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="admin_menu">
       contents of admin menu
</script>
```

and in `home.html` file I tried to include `admin_ menu` like:

```
  <ng-include src="'admin_menu'"></ng-include>
```

and this does not work. But if I put the above script tag part in index.html it works. index.html is the file which contains links to all js and app initialization. Do I have to define `admin_menu` page somewhere?

Comment: It seems to me that you need something like `<ng-include src="'/path/to/admin_menu.html'"></ng-include>` but I've never used angularjs before, I'm just reading the documentation.

Comment: Did you try something like: `<ng-include src="'partials/admin/admin_menu.html'"></ng-include>` ?

Comment: yes I tried giving the full path but it still does not work

Comment: @Sajana did yout full path include the `.html` extension? Your post lacks it, and it seems that's rather important.

Comment: I tried these <ng-include src="'admin_menu'"></ng-include> ,  <ng-include src="'/partials/admin/admin_menu.html'"></ng-include> <ng-include src="'/partials/admin/admin_menu'"></ng-include> <ng-include src="'admin/admin_menu.html'"></ng-include>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to include a template cache that is inside a separate `html` file.

Let's say you have `admin_menu.html`:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="admin_menu">
  stuff
</script>
```

And you want to include `admin_menu`. Normally you'd assume that using the code below should be fine.

```
<ng-include src="'admin_menu'></ng-include>
```

It would be fine if the script was in the same file where `ng-include` is located.

If want to load `admin_menu`, either remove the `<script>` tags inside `admin_menu.html` and include it normally.

admin_menu.html (no script wrapping the content):

```
contents of admin menu
```

home.html:

```
<ng-include src="'admin/admin_menu.html'"></ng-include>
```

OR

You can also include the admin menu as a template cache.

home.html:

```
<ng-include src="'admin_menu'"></ng-include>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="admin_menu">
       contents of admin menu
</script>
```

Here's a plunker showing how it works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Lw1Kx2k2aRedKQb1wjlG?p=preview

Note that if you inspect the code, you'll see that the script containing the content is loaded for the second `ng-include`.

Comment: 2nd case works for me but still the first condition is not working even if I remove the script tags

Comment: I don't know how you're loading in `home.html` but try `'partials/admin/admin_menu.html'`